# Fit guttering when shed roof extends further than expected

Tags: shed, gutters

I have recently bought a new shed and opted to not have the installers fit guttering thinking that I'd do it myself (c'mon, £200 for a bit of guttering is a bit steep!).

I've gone and bought some Floplast Miniflo guttering that is designed for sheds and smaller structures as it has a smaller 76mm diameter.

Getting it back home, I can now see that after mocking up the fit of the guttering, it appears that the roof extends further than expected and would miss the guttering completely. I approximate it to be between 30-50mm out.

Is there a way in which I can make this fit? Or would I be best returning the guttering and buying the regular sized stuff?

FYI - The shed walls are made out of 12mm T&G with substantial framing inside.

Comment: That's the choice between 200 quid and a learning experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to pack out the guttering with wood. Either strips a few inches long, where the brackets will go, or long strips, the whole length, so you can fit brackets wherever you like later. Strips will be 30-50 mm from shed side to out, filling your gap, and as deep (top-bottom) as the brackets need - maybe 2-3".

Comment: I had seen this as a potential solution that nobody ever made reference to in videos etc. I think it might be easier to do one long piece rather than individual pieces for brackets to sit on

Comment: @physicsboy   Long pieces are usually better.  If using wood would suggest very good prime and paint on all sides, or pressure treated wood.

Comment: @crip659 the shed has an oil based preservative on. Have bought some that I hope is the same shade, so I can get a piece coated and mounted :)

Comment: @physicsboy you might also consider using PVC "wood" trim. It's plastic so it'll last essentially forever. When you're repainting the shed, you won't have to worry about taking the gutters down to get to the hidden pieces of fascia because they won't need paint.